# Xamarin.Forms App with AppCenter crashes when offline (android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, crash, receiver

I integrated `AppCenters` notifications, crashes and analytics into my app
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/xamarin-forms...

Registered receiver in AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver
android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
     android:exported="false" /> 
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and everything is working fine ... Push notifications are working .. (most of the time)
i can see all the crashes and errors ...

BUT ... if i run the app offline (on most phones this happens only for the first time running) .. it crashes

```
Unhandled Exception from source=AppDomain 08-16 15:37:26.442 E/AppCenterCrashes( 8201): Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference 
08-16 15:37:26.442 E/AppCenterCrashes( 8201): 
--- End of managed Java.Lang.RuntimeException stack trace --- 
08-16 15:37:26.442 E/AppCenterCrashes( 8201): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference 
08-16 15:37:26.442 E/AppCenterCrashes( 8201): at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:714)  
08-16 15:37:26.442 E/AppCenterCrashes( 8201): at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzen(Unknown Source:2)  
08-16 15:37:26.442 E/AppCenterCrashes( 8201): at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zza(Unknown Source:5) 08-16  
08-16 15:37:26.442 E/AppCenterCrashes( 8201): at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zza(Unknown Source:80)  
08-16 15:37:26.442 E/AppCenterCrashes( 8201): at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.handleIntent(Unknown Source:158)  
08-16 15:37:26.442 E/AppCenterCrashes( 8201): at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source:4)  
08-16 15:37:26.442 E/AppCenterCrashes( 8201): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)  
08-16 15:37:26.442 E/AppCenterCrashes( 8201): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)  
08-16 15:37:26.442 E/AppCenterCrashes( 8201): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

But one Galaxy Core Prime Android 5.1.1 .. it crashes even if its connected ...

Any help or ideas ?

Comment: Crashes with this error on all the devices?

Comment: Yes, i have an Nexus 5, Huawei P20 Pro, Galaxy Core Prime, Oneplus 5T ... all of them crash with the same error if you are offline for the first time you run the app